# Using vscode as pager with VT100 extension, running `git log` works, but running `man man` doesn't

Tags: visual-studio-code, manpage, pager

This is the script I am using to make VSCode a pager:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$(mktemp pager.XXXXXX.ansi)
cat > $FILE
code --wait $FILE
rm $FILE
```

When I run `git log`, it does as I intend and opens a preview window in VSCode with colors etc. This is helpful for me as I don't want to have to expand the integrated terminal and would rather a window would open with long-form command output. However, this doesn't work with `man`.

If I run `man man`, I can see the temporary file get created, but the temporary file just gets promptly deleted with VSCode never opening. I tried looking online for resources and also argued with Copilot with no avail. I could accept that it doesn't work with `man` if I only knew *why*. My speculation is that `man` creates an environment that can't spawn vscode.